# Firebase Web-start Directory

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to do the ["Build a real-time web app" tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#4). It tells me to make sure I'm in the web-start directory, but web-start isn't a directory that I have. I see that there is something called "web-start" within "friendlychat" but I can only open them with vim, not cd into them.

This is what I see when I do $ vim friendlychat
[image: 2]

What do I need to do in order to be in the web-start directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you first need to go into the friendlychat directory and *then* into web-start.

```
cd friendlychat
cd web-start
```